# Error in date when using pandas to date time function

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('sales.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('sales1.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('sales2.csv')
df4 = pd.read_csv('sales3.csv')
df=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4])
df['Transaction date']
```

gives me the following output:

```
0     01/05/2018
1     30/04/2018
2     30/04/2018
3     25/04/2018
4     23/04/2018
5     23/04/2018
6     22/04/2018
7     22/04/2018
8     22/04/2018
9     21/04/2018
10    18/04/2018
11    18/04/2018
12    17/04/2018
13    17/04/2018
14    16/04/2018
15    15/04/2018
16    15/04/2018
17    15/04/2018
18    14/04/2018
19    14/04/2018
20    14/04/2018
21    13/04/2018
22    13/04/2018
23    13/04/2018
24    11/04/2018
25    11/04/2018
26    10/04/2018
27    09/04/2018
28    09/04/2018
29    07/04/2018
```

When I use `pd.to_datetime()`, some months and days change:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('sales.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('sales1.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('sales2.csv')
df4 = pd.read_csv('sales3.csv')
df=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4])
df['Transaction date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Transaction date'])
df['Transaction date']

0    2018-01-05
1    2018-04-30
2    2018-04-30
3    2018-04-25
4    2018-04-23
5    2018-04-23
6    2018-04-22
7    2018-04-22
8    2018-04-22
9    2018-04-21
10   2018-04-18
11   2018-04-18
12   2018-04-17
13   2018-04-17
14   2018-04-16
15   2018-04-15
16   2018-04-15
17   2018-04-15
18   2018-04-14
19   2018-04-14
20   2018-04-14
21   2018-04-13
22   2018-04-13
23   2018-04-13
24   2018-11-04
25   2018-11-04
26   2018-10-04
27   2018-09-04
28   2018-09-04
29   2018-07-04
```

from output 24 to 29 the month and date switch. I want to change the column `Transaction date` to a `datetime64[ns]` type but want to have my dates in one format `yyyy/mm/dd`.

Above is the format: `dd/mm/yyyy` and with `pd.to_datetime()` it should change to `yyyy-mm-dd`. This works from output 0 to 23 but from output 24 to 29 it changes from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `yyyy-dd-mm`. I want all dates to `datetime64[ns]` type in the same format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

I can't find a solution, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the format it seems to be solved:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Transaction date'], format = '%d/%m/%Y')
```